# Create a virtual reality environment : seek suggestions

Tags: unity

Im running on a Oculus Rift Integrated OS. I am trying to gather information about how I would go about creating a virtual reality environment. Where a users actions through their control panel and their home location (a 3d virtual environment they can walk around in) would launch at power state `on` of the computer.

I saw that there is a 3d implementation of Ubuntu Unity, and I was wondering if you could point me in the direction. Here I can find any information on utilizing OpenGL to display my custom 3d game-like environment with direct access to Ubuntu. It is as if the user was on a standard desktop.

Any suggestions ?